# Getting error try to select hive table using hcatalog from HAWQ

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, hawq

I am using Hortonworks (HDP)sandbox and on top of that install HAWQ 2.0

I'm trying to select hive table using `hcatalog` but not able to access hive tables form HAWQ. Executing below steps mention in pivotal doc.

```
postgres=# SET pxf_service_address TO "localhost:51200";

SET

postgres=# select count(*) from hcatalog.default.sample_07;


ERROR: remote component error (500) from 'localhost:51200': type Exception report message Internal server error. Property &quot;METADATA&quot; has no value in current request description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal server error. Property &quot;METADATA&quot; has no value in current request (libchurl.c:878)

LINE 1: select count(*) from hcatalog.default.sample_07;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a missing property in pxf-profile.xml 
check if you have `<metadata>` property under `Hive` profile

this is newly added profile and if you were using a legacy build it might not have it.

 `<profile>
        <name>Hive</name>
        <description>This profile is suitable for using when connecting to Hive</description>
        <plugins>
            <fragmenter>org.apache.hawq.pxf.plugins.hive.HiveDataFragmenter</fragmenter>
            <accessor>org.apache.hawq.pxf.plugins.hive.HiveAccessor</accessor>
            <resolver>org.apache.hawq.pxf.plugins.hive.HiveResolver</resolver>
<metadata>org.apache.hawq.pxf.plugins.hive.HiveMetadataFetcher</metadata>
        </plugins>
    </profile>`

Comment: Add the above mention line in the pxf-profiles.xml but still giving me the same error.

Comment: What I observed when I add the line in pxf-profiles.xml and after that restart the PXF, its again reset <metadata> line was removed.

Comment: Thanks Goden Yao, its working, update the changes from Ambari.